# One-loop renormalization of $\phi^4$ theory in Cheng and Li

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, perturbation-theory, self-energy

In Gauge Theory of Elementary particle Physics by Cheng and Li, They manipulate the self-energy 1PI vertex as

[image]

[image]

I am quite confused how one gets (2.20), what type of expansion is this?

Comment: hint: consider (2.16)